# 500: Internal Server Error on trying to run an existing grails application after on a mac system

Tags: grails, setup-project

I am partially done through the setup - 
 - setup grails 2.4.0 , jdk 1.7.0, gradle 5.4.1, but now I checked that this version of gradle is incompatible with jdk 7.
 - copied the .grails folder contents from earlier working setup.
 - took code into sew working directorty.

I am able to run grails and run-app, but when I browse to the application URL, I get a 500 error, with the following stacktrace -

```
Trace
    Line | Method
->>  527 | doFilter  in /Users/sandeepan.nath/Desktop/codebase/some-consumer-portal/grails-app/views/linkLogin/index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: Cannot get property 'application' on null object
->>   11 | doCall    in /Users/sandeepan.nath/Desktop/codebase/some-consumer-portal/grails-app/views/linkLogin/index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'application' on null object
->>   37 | run       in Users_sandeepan_nath_Desktop_codebase_some_consumer_portal_grails_app_views_include__head_gsp

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     29 | doCall    in Users_sandeepan_nath_Desktop_codebase_some_consumer_portal_grails_app_views_linkLogin_index_gsp$_run_closure1
|     36 | run . . . in Users_sandeepan_nath_Desktop_codebase_some_consumer_portal_grails_app_views_linkLogin_index_gsp
|    198 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

[image]

Comment: What is the code for line 527 in views/linkLogin/index.gsp ?

Comment: Is "on a mac system" really a suspect here (does it work on other OSs)?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example using a fresh installation of Grails 2.4.0?